# Having some issues with views in SFML

Tags: c++, sfml

so I'm new to stack overflow and programming in general, so forgive me if I do or say anything blatantly stupid out of ignorance.

So, I've been trying to learn how to use SFML recently, and so far, it's been going fine, but recently, I've been trying to program a moving camera. Let me show you my code:

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <SFML/Audio.hpp>

#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;
using namespace sf;

bool frame60 = true;

void print(string inputText) {
    bool consoleOn = true;
    if(consoleOn == true) { cout << inputText; }
}

void start() {
    sf::View view1;
    view1.reset(sf::FloatRect(300, 200, 300, 200));
    view1.setCenter(0, 0);

    RenderWindow window(VideoMode(1600, 900), "Test Game");
    window.setView(view1);
    window.setKeyRepeatEnabled(false);
    switch(frame60) {
    case true:
        window.setFramerateLimit(60);
        break;
    case false:
        window.setFramerateLimit(30);
        break;
    default:
        window.setFramerateLimit(60);
        break;
    }

    Texture testure;
    testure.loadFromFile("vsm.png");
    Sprite testsprite;
    testsprite.setTexture(testure);

    testsprite.setOrigin(0, 0);

    float playerx = 0;
    float playery = 0;


    while(window.isOpen()) {
        Event event;
        while(window.pollEvent(event)) {
            switch(event.type) {
                //Making the window closable
            case Event::Closed:
                window.clear();
                window.close();
                break;
            }
        }

        if(Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::A)) {
            playerx += 0.5;
        }
        if(Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::D)) {
            playerx -= 0.5;
        }

        testsprite.setOrigin(playerx, playery);

        view1.setCenter(playerx, playery);
        window.draw(testsprite);
        window.display();
        window.clear();

        cout << playerx << endl;
    }
}

int main() {
    start();
    return 0;
}
```

(don't mind me using a self made start function, that's just me experimenting to get a better idea of how to use c++ in general. as is probably the case with a lot of unnecessary parts of this program, as this program is just a learning exercise.)

So, basically, as you can see, I have a blue rectangle that moves. However, I want the camera to follow it, so in the game loop, I tell my view to set its center to where the rectangle is. Pretty basic. Problem is, the screen doesn't move. I press the left and right keys I set, and I still see the box moving over the black background, when if the view was following it, it wouldn't appear to move at all, and the only evidence that it is moving should be in my console window.

What is it I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to make any change to the view of the window, you have to call `sf::RenderWindow::setView` afterwards. You're just modifying `view1`, not the copy that `sf::RenderWindow` stores and uses.

[**Reference**](http://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.0/classsf_1_1RenderTarget.php#a063db6dd0a14913504af30e50cb6d946)

I would do this view updating in additional scope, not to pollute the outer scope:

```
{
    sf::View view = window.getView(); // get the current view, view1 is not needed here
    // modify the view
    window.setView(view);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, you really helped me out.

Comment: @AxleRe You should also read the [Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), if you haven't. That'll help you avoid bad questions. You don't have to worry about this one, it's an above-the-average-first-question.